# Factorial implementation using FixedPoint

Tags: recursion

I implemented the factorial function:

```
fact[0] = 1
fact[x_Integer?Positive ] := x*fact[x - 1];
```

f[4] yields 24 as expected

I tried a different version of the factorial function using FixedPoint. I added factAlt[1] = 1 to help SameTest (or rather Equal) conclude that the same result has been produced (when reaching factAlt[1] and factAlt[0]).

```
factAlt[0] = 1
factAlt[1] = 1
factAlt[n_ /; n >= 1] := n*factAlt[n - 1]
FixedPoint[factAlt, 4, SameTest -> Equal]
```

This version does not seem to terminate.

I am new to FixedPoint in Mathematica (and have some mileage in lambda calculus).

Can you advise on how to implement factorial correctly using FixedPoint?

Could the issue be that when factAlt[1] is reached, SameTest does not access factAlt[1] = 1 (which is listed separately) and thus SameTest given will not conclude that factAlt[1] and factAlt[0] are the same (?).

ETA. I clearly misinterpreted the function of FixedPoint. Accepted Lukas Lang's answer which is closest to the spirit of the question.

Comment: Read the documentation for FixedPoint. Or try this: `FixedPoint[factAlt, 4, 2]`. It keeps applying `factAlt` to the result, so it just explodes.

Comment: Are you really asking "how to implement factorial correctly using FixedPoint"? Or are you just trying to understand why your `FixedPoint` expression doesn't terminate?

Comment: Yes, clearly I was entirely on the wrong track here. The question is how to implement factorial using FixedPoint.

Comment: Let's say we had `fact[n_]:=FixedPoint[fun,n]`. Given, say, 4, we're saying that at some point `fun[fun[...fun[fun[4]]...]]` becomes fixed at `4!`. In particular, `f[24]==24`. But this must be true for every `n`, so `f[n!]==n!` in general. But if `f[24]==24`, then `fact[24]==24` and therefore `fact[24] =!= 24!`.

Comment: Now, there are other ways we could use `FixedPoint`. Like maybe we use a different structure that keeps track of the level of nesting. E.g. `fact[n_]:=First[FixedPoint[fun,{n,n}]]` where `fun` somehow decremented the second element of its argument and continued building the product in its first argument. I haven't worked out the details, but I suspect you could define `fun` so that it appropriately stayed fixed for `{x,0}` such that `x==n!`.

Comment: As @lericr noted you can store the state with multiple inputs, here is the code for 5: `First@FixedPoint[{Times @@ #, Last[#] - 1} &, {5, 5 - 1}, 5 - 1]`, if you prefer not using the third argument, you can use `First@FixedPoint[{Times@@#,Last[#]-1}&,{5,5-1},SameTest->(Last@#2==0&)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FixedPoint` is not doing what you think it does: It evaluates the sequence `facAlt[4]`, `facAlt[facAlt[4]]`, etc. This yields $4!=24$, $24!=620448401733239000000000$, etc. which will never reach a fixed point. Unfortunately, I don't see a good way to use `FixedPoint` to define the factorial.

One way to try and find an explicit `FixedPoint` is the following:

1. Instead of relying on Mathematica's evaluation, we implement it ourselves using `ReplaceRepeated`:

   ```
   factAlt[4] //. {factAlt[0] -> 1, factAlt[n_] :> n*factAlt[n - 1]}
   (* 24 *)
   ```
2. We can now note that `ReplaceRepeated` is effectively `ReplaceAll` with `FixedPoint`:

   ```
   FixedPoint[
    ReplaceAll@{factAlt[0] -> 1, factAlt[n_] :> n*factAlt[n - 1]},
    factAlt[4]
    ]
   (* 24 *)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I rephrased the question. You answer shows where I went wrong. I want to implement the factorial function using the FixedPoint operator (if possible).

Comment: @Michel Please don't edit questions like that. It invalidates all the existing answers & comments. Instead, simply mark this question as answered and ask a new one

Comment: @Michel Also, see my edit for a way to force an explicit `FixedPoint` into the picture, but it really doesn't gain you anything

Comment: thanks. Appreciate the comments and the solution. I added a comment to the question as I'm interested in a broader interpretation as well.

Comment: @Michel Is there a reason why you are not simply asking a new question? While you now preserved the original content of your question, your "broader question" is so far removed from the original that all answers/comments are worthless in regards to answering it. I am not saying your new question isn't a good question to ask, simply that it doesn't belong inside this question. The goal of Stackexchange is to produce Q&A posts for single, isolated questions, not constantly evolving discussions.

Comment: Ok, will repost in another question, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt:

```
factStep[{0, _}] := {1, 0};
factStep[{f_, 0}] := {f, 0};
factStep[{f_, n_}] := factStep[{n f, n - 1}];

myFact[n_Integer?NonNegative] := First[FixedPoint[factStep, {n, n - 1}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, just noticed your answer. Kept my original vote for Lang as it came close to what I asked originally.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fac[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 FixedPoint[{#[[1]] - 1, Times @@ #} &, {n, 1}, 
   SameTest -> (#1[[2]] == #2[[2]] &)][[-1]]
```

Test:

```
And @@ Table[fac[n] == n!, {n, 1, 10}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for FixedPoint. The definition alone will do what you want:

```
factAlt[0] = 1
factAlt[1] = 1
factAlt[n_ /; n >= 1] := n*factAlt[n - 1]
factAlt[4]

(* 24 *)
```

Comment: I realise this. I just wonder if it can be done.